# How to Rank in Rails After Grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my Rails 6 app where I'm using Postgres, I have a table called `UserCategories`.

```
| id | user_id | category_id | points| rank |
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Group the records by category_id
2. Sort the records for each category_id by points (desc)
3. Update the rank field based on the order the record is in for the category_id

Example (desired rank determined by the points per category_id):

```
| id | user_id | category_id | points| rank |
| 1  |    1    |    1        |   2   |     |  #  I want rank to be 1
| 2  |    2    |    1        |   1   |     |  #  I want rank to be 2
| 3  |    1    |    2        |   3   |     |  #  I want rank to be 1
| 4  |    2    |    2        |   3   |     |  #  I want rank to be 1
```

My model method:

```
  def self.calculate_user_category_ranks
    @user_categories = UserCategory.select(:id, :points, :user_id, :category_id, :rank).all.order(points: :desc).group_by(&:category_id)
    # returns: 
    #   {2=>[#<UserCategory:0x000000000de8be00 id: 2, user_id: 1, category_id: 2, points: 3, rank: 0>, #<UserLeague:0x000000000de8bce8 id: 4, user_id: 2, category_id: 2, points: 3, rank: 0>],
         1=>[#<UserCategory:0x000000000de8bbf8 id: 1, user_id: 1, category_id: 1, points: 2, rank: 0>, <UserLeague:0x000000000de8bb30 id: 3, user_id: 2, category_id: 1, points: 1, rank: 0>]}

    rank = 0
    points_counter = 0

    @user_categories.each do |id, points|
      uc = UserCategory.find(id)
      
      if points != point_counter
        rank += 1
        point_counter = points
      end

      uc.rank = rank
      uc.save
    end
  end
```

After I execute this code:

```
| id | user_id | category_id | points| rank |
| 1  |    1    |    1        |   2   |  2  |  #  I want rank to be 1
| 2  |    2    |    1        |   1   |  0  |  #  I want rank to be 2
| 3  |    1    |    2        |   3   |  1  |  #  I want rank to be 1
| 4  |    2    |    2        |   3   |  0  |  #  I want rank to be 1
```

Can someone please help me determine what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it will be less expensive if you process your rank query in the database https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/

Answer (score 0):

You may be choosing to put `rank` as a database column for reasons of efficiency, but the principles of database normalization would suggest that it is "bad practice" to have a column whose value is calculable from the other columns in the table. So, recognizing that you may not accept this solution for reasons of efficiency, let me suggest that, for any particular instance of `UserCategory` you can determine its rank in Ruby:

```rb
class UserCategory < ApplicationRecord
  scope :in_the_same_category, ->(category_id) { where("category_id = ?", category_id }

  def in_my_category
    UserCategory.in_the_same_category(category_id)
  end

  def rank
    in_my_category.
      sort_by(&:points).
      reverse.
      map(&:points).
      uniq.
      index(points) + 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
UserCategory.group(:category_id)
```

Then build it up

If you really need to restrict the fields returned or add a where clause then

```
UserCategory.where(some_field: "some_value").select(:id, :points, :user_id, :category_id, :rank).group(:category_id).order(:points :desc)
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group for more info